# Dynamic column change

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wondering if in Excel there is a way to change columns as described below?

```
=A1*(Formula that returns a letter)2
```

so for example the formula returns the letter F the result would be
`=A1*F2`

then if in cell A1 = `3`, and F2 = `7`. then where the Excel formula is the result would be `21`.

I am hoping this approach is possible as I am hoping to use it in a `SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(.......................................))` where the data I am analyzing is in a mess of columns and labels. and am confused with what else I can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) can take text-that-looks-like-a-cell-reference and convert it into a valid cell reference.

```
=INDIRECT("A2")
=INDIRECT("A"&2)
=INDIRECT(<formula that returns a letter>&2)
=INDIRECT(<formula that returns a letter>&"2")
```

... each of these is the the same as,

```
=A2
```

All you have to do is pass along some constructed text string that can be interpreted as a cell reference into INDIRECT.

Caution should be exercised when using the INDIRECT function as it is considered a **volatile**¹ function. If they are used in calculation-intensive formulas or very prolifically, the user will experience calculation lag whenever anything in the workbook changes.

---

¹ <sub>Volatile functions recalculate whenever anything in the entire workbook changes, not just when something that affects their outcome changes. Examples of **volatile** functions are [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd), [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592), [TODAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-62B76639-BA50-4F86-AD4E-1A74FB2EA566), [NOW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NOW-function-3337FD29-145A-4347-B2E6-20C904739C46), [RAND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RAND-function-4CBFA695-8869-4788-8D90-021EA9F5BE73) and [RANDBETWEEN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANDBETWEEN-function-4CC7F0D1-87DC-4EB7-987F-A469AB381685). Some sub-functions of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) and [INFO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INFO-function-725f259a-0e4b-49b3-8b52-58815c69acae) worksheet functions will make them volatile as well.</sub>

Comment: @Ethan_Moe - If you are having trouble incorporating this into a complex formula, edit your question to include the more complex formula and assistance will likely be offered.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will attempt to incorrperate it, and if I struggle I will update my post.